# Open custom outgoing port on Openshift cloud

Tags: node.js, networking, permissions, openshift, steam

I'm trying to get an app working using [node-steam](https://github.com/seishun/node-steam) but am having some problems.

It works fine on my local machine but I get the following error and my application crashes shortly after.

```
events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: bind EACCES 0.0.0.0
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:893:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:916:20)
    at dgram.js:221:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

It seems to open a connection to one of Steam's servers through port 27019, How do I get openshift to allow my application to connect to that server?

Answer (score 0):

You can not bind to all interfaces (0.0.0.0) or localhost (127.0.0.1) on OpenShift Online.  You MUST bind to the ip address which is assigned to your gear, which is available by either:

1. Using the `OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP` environment variable in your code `process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP` (recommended)
2. SSHing into your gear and using the `"env + grep NODEJS_IP`" command to view the value of the `OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP` environment variable and statically including it in your code (not recommended)

Comment: I don't think I'm trying to bind to a port, The source code is [here](https://github.com/seishun/node-steam) and it's not my library. I looked and I couldn't find anything about binding or anything

Comment: I found out where the problem was, it was in node-ssq rather than node-steam. I am still having a problem with this, I get Error: send EPERM 146.66.157.74:27021 when my app is trying to get data from a source server. Should I make a different question for this? It seems unrelated.

Comment: *bump* Should I make a new question for this?